# ember.js: is it possible to connect an outlet to applicationController?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Why is it it necessary to always create views and controllers?
Isn't it possible to say: each view that does not have a specific controller class, falls back to using the applicationController instance, when is being attached as an outlet.

Possible?

Comment: Ember is not allowing to break the architecture so that you are compelled to use stricter MVC and end up happier at the end, cheers. When you strictly follow MVC each controller is supposed to be having specific logic, so how can you suppose Orphan views to follow the applicationController logic? On the other hand, what led you this thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connectOutlet` method has a `controller` option you can pass:

```
postsController.connectOutlet('createPost', { controller: 'application' })
```

That said, we are in the process of improving the router API in general to put a greater focus on templates and making the View class optional (you'll only need one if you have events to handle).